# What are the rules for inheritance for women?

Tags: catholicism

Are there any rules for inheritance for women in the Roman Catholic creed?

It would be helpful if you could provide the verse for reference.

Comment: The Catholic Creed is the same as any other (notwithstanding the *filioque* controversy). Could you be more specific?

Comment: Inheritance is governed by civil law. Churches don't get to control it. If you mean in the Vatican, I'm pretty sure there's not a lot of children inheriting their parent's money there.

Comment: @DJClayworth hahaah, very funny.  Ok so there is no law then?

Comment: There is Canon Law about inheritances, but not in the Creeds.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Can you please tell me what that is? Canon Law and creed are still binding to believe in right?

Comment: I assume by Canon law he means Jewish law (old testament), which doesn't have any inheritance for women that I know of.  Firstborn sons got a double-portion...so 3 sons, first son gets 50%, second two sons get 25% each.  If you didn't have any sons, your wife married your brother (a "kinsman redeemer") who would have children on your behalf so that your inheritance would go to those children of your wife.  You must remember that Jewish law was both religious and civil law. Most Christians don't observe the civil aspects of Judaism.

Comment: @KevinNelson No, that's not what Canon Law is.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Sorry for my ignorance of Catholicism...I usually only hear the word "canon" associated with scripture so took a stab at it.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: [Canon law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_law) And not just for Catholics.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about civil law

Answer (score 3):

The Catholic Creeds are statements of Faith; they define what Christianity is. They are broadly ecumenical, because they are early documents, and there aren't many differences in what different branches of Christianity use. The [Catholic versions](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/credo.htm) are available on the Vatican website. Because they are statements of Faith, they do not touch on law.

Canon Law is the rules of the Church itself, and the [Code of Canon Law](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/_INDEX.HTM) is also available on the Vatican website. That *does* mention, once, briefly, [inheritances](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/_P5A.HTM):

> **1413** A party can be brought to trial:
>   1: in cases which concern administration, before the tribunal of the place where the administration was conducted;
>   2: in cases which regard inheritances or pious legacies, before the tribunal of the last domicile, quasi-domicile, or place of residence ... of the one whose inheritance or pious legacy is at issue unless it concerns the mere execution of the legacy, which must be examined according to the ordinary norms of competence.

This is specifying which ecclesiastical court is competent to deal with queries about inheritances. In most countries, inheritance is subject to the civil law and the Church would not be involved in the matter, especially since most queries relate to how a will is executed.

There is nothing **in Canon Law** about who may inherit or bequeath.

It is possible, I suppose, that  a will may bequeath part of an estate to a religious house or order whose own statutes stipulate what should be done with the bequest. The will's executors satisfy the bequest (which takes it out of their hands) and perhaps some dispute arises about how the order's statutes apply. That **might** come before an ecclesiastical tribunal; but even there — in the UK at least — the order is likely to be a registered charity and be subject to the jurisdiction of civil regulators.

*Note:* Neither I nor Stack Exchange provide legal advice. Do not use this answer to formulate any opinion on any particular case. For advice concerning specific circumstances, you must consult a competent lawyer.